# How to install "fonts available for download" from terminal

Tags: terminal, font, font-book

In this [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208968), it says:

> ### Fonts available for download in Mojave
>
> To download and enable any of these fonts:
>
> 1. Open Font Book from your Applications folder.
> 2. Select All Fonts in the sidebar, or use the Search field to find the font that you want to download. Fonts that aren't already downloaded appear dimmed in the list of fonts.
> 3. Select the dimmed font and choose Edit > Download, or Control-click it and choose Download from the pop-up menu.

But how to install these fonts from terminal? I know that the fonts can be directly copy to the folder, but where and how can I get these fonts?

Comment: From looking at the net traffic generated the download seems to come from a cryptic location within the Apple Content Delivery Network. Collecting all these URL might be possible (but nobody guarantees that they won't change), so I'm wondering whether there is an official source as well.